# hook to win message (WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING) of other process' windows

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to hook directly into window size changes (before or while it is happening) to set other applications from changing its size.

If i use WinEvent hook (thanks pinvoke), I can receive EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART but only when user manually tries to resize them. If a program attempts to do it on itself (probably through SetWindowPos), it won't fire.

My hope is to hook into WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING and deny it.

```
  pwp->flags |= SWP_NOSIZE;
  return FORWARD_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING(hwnd, pwp, DefWindowProc);
```

this is pretty much how I would do it if I can hook WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING.

Comment: WinEvent was meant to notify you, not to affect the way the window works.  That requires a very different kind of hook, a WH_CALLWNDPROC hook, so you can mess with the WM_MOVE and WM_SIZE messages.  And WM_NCHITTEST so you don't confuse the stuffing out of the user.  You can't write such hooks in C# since it requires code injection.

Comment: Hi philippoe, why do you want to prevent other programs resize themselves?